# OpenWRT empty folder can't be deleted (rm -rf|rmdir) nor listed (ls) show: No error information

Tags: ls, rm, openwrt

I've been having some issues with the filesystem in an embedded computer that runs OpenWRT. Suddenly, I'm not able to delete certain folders that are empty.

I get these error messages that are very confusing:

```
root@Omega-9439:/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages# rm -rf tmp/
rm: can't stat 'tmp/_reloader.py': No error information
rm: can't stat 'tmp/datastructures.py': No error information
rm: can't stat 'tmp/_internal.py': No error information
rm: can't stat 'tmp/middleware': No error information
rm: can't stat 'tmp/__pycache__': No error information
rm: can't stat 'tmp/wrappers': No error information
rm: can't stat 'tmp/_compat.py': No error information
rm: can't stat 'tmp/__init__.py': No error information
rm: can't remove 'tmp': Directory not empty
```

Those were files that used to be inside the folder but that doesn't exist now.

```
root@Omega-9439:/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tmp# ll
ls: ./_reloader.py: No error information
ls: ./datastructures.py: No error information
ls: ./_internal.py: No error information
ls: ./middleware: No error information
ls: ./__pycache__: No error information
ls: ./wrappers: No error information
ls: ./_compat.py: No error information
ls: ./__init__.py: No error information
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Nov 11 12:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x   69 root     root          4096 Nov 11 15:24 ../
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> sudo rmdir  --ignore-fail-on-non-empty folder-name-to-be-deleted

After this, try your command to delete the dir.

Not sure if this would resolve. If it still fails, then I suppose your filesystem is corrupted. Try running fsck against the /tmp partition and repair your filesystem. You shouldn't run fsck on root filesystem in live environment. However /tmp should be fine.

Comment: Hi @Gokul thanks for your answer, unfortunately adding the flag `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty folder-name-to-be-deleted` just make the command ignore the error. I will try the option of recovering the filesystem.